# Making an EDIT button work

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<a href="#" data-target="#edit-order value="<?php echo $users[$i]['id']; ?>" name="delete-order" id="bb-confirm" data-placement="left" data-rel="tooltip" data-toggle="modal" data-original-title="Delete Order" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times icon-only"></i></a>
```

I want to parse the "value" info to this edit-order form and i didn't  manage to make it work. I've tried with GET but nothing.

```
<div class="modal fade modal-scroll" id="edit-order" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Ã—</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add Order</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body padding-2x">

                    <form role="form" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Order ID #</label>
                            <?php echo ORDER-ID-PASSED-FROM-BUTTON; ?>
                        </div>   

                        <div class="form-actions no-padding-bottom">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <button type="submit" name="edit-order" class="btn btn-primary">Update Order</button>
                            </div>          
                        </div>                                              
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Can somebody help me with this ? Thanks a lot

Comment: I would like to fetch the value id from the button into the form... I would like to keep the button as is...

Comment: There is no meaning of value into "<a>" . Please check  at [W3c](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

Comment: is html for edit-order modal always in DOM or is it created dynamically?

Comment: It's always the same

Comment: You didn't closed data-target attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If your modal dialog stay in the DOM you can use this code:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('[data-target="#edit-order"]');
[].forEach.call(links, function(link) {
   link.onclick = function() {
      var value = link.getAttribute('value');
      var group = document.querySelector('.modal form .form-group');
      var input = document.querySelector('.modal form .form-group input');
      if (input) {
          group.removeChild(input);
      }
      input = document.createElement('input');
      input.setAttribute('value', value);
      input.setAttribute('name', 'order');
      group.appendChild(input);
   };
});
```

or using jQuery:

```
$('[data-target="#edit-order"]').click(function() {
   $('.modal form .form-group input').remove();
   var value = $(this).attr('value');
   $('.modal form .form-group').append('<input name="order" value="' + value + '"/>');
});
```

Comment: Isn't there any simpler way ? I'm not a pro coder and i can't manage to add this myself

Comment: @Adrian No, you need to create input with value dynamically, this is the shortest code possible that do just that. jQuery version don't have much code in it.

Comment: i will create hidden input with value dynamicaly, but how will i pass it on to the #edit-order popup form ?